# C# Tasks Locking with use of SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking, task, semaphore

Below I have code that adds Tasks to a list of all currently running tasks that I can later use. I use a semaphore to ensure that there isn't problems with adding / removing to the List, -- and I only start the Task once it has been added to the List

My problem is that if the my SomeTask -- contains UI operations, I am unsure what is the best way to get around this issue.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
SemaphoreSlim SemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

async Task Lock(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    action();
  }
  finally
  {
    SemaphoreSlim.Release();
  }
}

public async Task SomeTask
{
   ///Some UI Operations occur here
}
public async void CreateTaskToPool()
{
  var task = new Task(() => SomeTask));

  await Lock(() => tasks.Add(task));
  task.Start();
  var control = await task;
  await Lock(() => tasks.Remove(task));
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have any other suggestions of implementing this Task Pool better -- feel free to suggest

Comment: First of all: Why do you need such a task pool at all? Perhaps you are trying to do something that isn't necessary. Second: SemaphorSlim is meant for short waits and in the case of such a task pool, you probably don't know how long these task will run. Better to use the Semaphore class instead.

Comment: What is the reasoning for using a `SemaphoreSlim` instead of a simpler `lock`? It seams that you just want to synchronize access to a shared resource (the `List<Task> tasks`). And adding/removing a single element to a list is not particularly CPU intensive.

Comment: @Silvermind `Semaphore` does not support asynchronous waits.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well, unless the list is large and it needs to copy all of the values over to a new backing array.  The time of a List add for a single item scale with the size of the list after all.  Although presumably this list is not going to get all that large?

Comment: There's no reason to use `SemaphoreSlim` here instead of `lock`. There's also no reason to use the `Task` constructor. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, why the UI code is a problem, and why any of this code exists at all.

Comment: I think you are all right tho that in this case -- it isn't possible for a deadlock to occur. So a regular lock is fine

Comment: @IlanKeshet tasks are not jumping from thread to thread at arbitrary points of execution. A thread jump can only occur after an `await`. I bet my pet snake that you'll never see a thread change after adding (or removing) synchronously an element in a list!